# Comando sort linux enviar salida a otro archivo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, línea-de-comandos, filesystem

tengo que hacer esto con el comando sort pero no se como sería lo de la salida:

> Ordenar el fichero /usr/dict/words o /usr/share/dict/words en orden
> inverso usando el comando sort y enviar la salida del comando al
> fichero word.sort en el directorio temp
> creado. Mostrar word.sort.

lo que hice hasta ahora es meterme en el directorio y ejecutar este comando

```
sort -r words
```

hasta ahí todo bien pero mi pregunta es: Cómo mando la salida del comando al fichero en el directorio temp? me fije en el directorio temp y solo tengo esto

```
joakov3@Joako-linux:/tmp$ ls
config-err-HpwbvZ
snap.snap-store
ssh-67qnryvjYX1U
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-apache2.service-ThBIai
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-bolt.service-zkdEBi
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-colord.service-LPFflh
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-ModemManager.service-tBL9Li
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-switcheroo-control.service-huOuhf
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-systemd-logind.service-tzYwUe
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-systemd-resolved.service-biRpIh
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-systemd-timesyncd.service-uMm0Tf
systemd-private-110795de8cfa484cbf2b2d98a6f5c74d-upower.service-t19Vah
tmp.q1kIAPAwkg
tracker-extract-files.1000
tracker-extract-files.125
```

espero que puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar *redirección* con `>` o `>>`, o lo que corresponda. Hay más *operadores* (término adecuado?) para manejar salida de stderr, o juntar ambos streams de salida de un proceso, etc. Altamente relacionado con los `|`s

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html